# Methods to solve this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation?

$$
A\;\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} + B\cos(\theta) +C\sin(\theta) = 0
$$

Answer (score 3):

First note that
\begin{align}
B\cos\theta + C\sin\theta =&\ \sqrt{B^2+C^2}\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}\cos\theta + \frac{C}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}\sin\theta \right)\\
=&\ \sqrt{B^2+C^2} \sin(\theta + \delta) = D \sin(\theta+\delta)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\cos\delta = \frac{C}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}} \ \text{ and } \ \sin\delta = \frac{B}{\sqrt{B^2+C^2}}.
\end{align}

Hence, your differential equation becomes
\begin{align}
A \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+ D \sin(\theta+\delta)=0.
\end{align}
In particular, if you define a new function $\phi(t) = \theta(t) + \delta$, i.e. shift by a constant, then we see that $\phi$ satisfies
\begin{align}
A\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} = A\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} = - D\sin(\theta +\delta) = -D\sin(\phi).
\end{align}
Hence you have the equation
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}+\frac{D}{A}\sin(\phi)=0.
\end{align}
This is just the [standard pendulum equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)) which can be "readily solved".